# how make loop work out of function in php code?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 <?php function getnews()
{

global $db;

$news=$db->query("select * from news order by news_id desc");

$row=$news->fetch_object();

return $row;

}?>
```

`

```
foreach (getnews() as $result)
 { 
   echo $result->news_title . "<br>";
 }
?>
```

but foreach not work out of function

any help

Comment: Can you provide any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getnews()` function only ever returns a single row from the database, even though your query will fetch them all.... perhaps consider a loop in the `getnews()` function that returns each one in turn, maybe using a generator so that you can use them in a `foreach` loop

```
function getnews() {
    global $db;
    $news=$db->query("select * from news order by news_id desc");
    while ($row=$news->fetch_object()) {
        yield $row;
    }
}

foreach (getnews() as $result) { 
   echo $result->news_title . "<br>";
}
```

Though using a generator does require PHP >= 5.5

If you're using an earlier version of PHP, then build an array in `getnews()` and return that, but it isn't as efficient:

```
function getnews() {
    global $db;
    $news=$db->query("select * from news order by news_id desc");
    $items = array();
    while ($row=$news->fetch_object()) {
        $items[] = $row;
    }
    return $items;
}

foreach (getnews() as $result) { 
   echo $result->news_title . "<br>";
}
```